# What is Fin(E,2)?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, forcing

> It is easy to see that Bor(I) satisfies the c.c.c., because the measures add up to at most 1. Fin(E,2) is also c.c.c., but the proof is more difficult. (Countable chain condition, wikipedia)

So what is Fin(E,2)?

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{Fin} ( E , 2 )$ is the set of all finite partial functions $E \to 2 = \{ 0 , 1 \}$, and the ordering is reverse inclusion: $p \leq q$ iff $p \supseteq q$, or, more pedantically, $\mathrm{dom} ( p ) \supseteq \mathrm{dom} ( p )$ and $p (e) = q(e)$ for all $e \in \mathrm{dom}(q)$.

Comment: Actually the reverse inclusion is formally correct. I also like how your advisors work with Shelah and are therefore bound by his up-notation, but you resist! Very good!

Comment: @Asaf: I think that Jakob and Martin often take their Shelah notes and rewrite everything to follow the proper "western" convention.  But I do generally avoid using the "alphabet convention" whose popularisation was one of the intended goals of Martin's _A taste of proper forcing_.

Comment: Alphabet convention?

Comment: @Asaf: Lexicographically earlier symbols for conditions are never stronger than lexicographically later ones.  (So if in a paper you see either "$q \leq p$" or "$p \leq q$" this means $q$ is stronger than $p$ without having to figure out whether Shelah was one of the co-authors.)

Comment: Oh. That makes sense.

Comment: I’m amused by the *more difficult* comment: in my mental universe the $\Delta$-system lemma is simpler than almost anything involving the word *Borel* or the word *measure*!

Comment: @Brian: I did a bit of a double-take on that as well.